# How do you remove falsy values with .splice?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove all falsy values(false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN) from an array. My research showed that .filter() is the proper way to accomplish this, but I had already been trying to solve my problem with the code below and I don't understand why .splice only seems to be removing "" when I want it to also remove false.

The goal is to return [7, "ate", 9] but when i'm getting is [7, "ate", false, 9]

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (Boolean(arr[i]) === false){
      arr.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Comment: `[7, "ate", "", false, 9].filter(function(val){return !!val;}) -> [7, "ate", 9]`

Comment: This works as well: `[7, "ate", "", false, 9].filter(function(val){return val;})`

Comment: Also, a hard to spot issue: `for (i = 0...` should have `var` like `for (var i = 0...` to keep it local.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that [**.splice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=example) call is changing the `length` of the array, so in the next iteration after removing `""` the `i` will point to the last element and skips the `false` index.

If you check the [**splice()** MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you will see that:

> Description
>
> If you specify a different number of elements to insert than the
>   number you're removing, the array will have a different length at the
>   end of the call.

**Demo:**

Here's a demo logging the iterated elements and showing that the `false` value was skipped:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    if (Boolean(arr[i]) === false) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

**Solution:**

As a solution you can use an inversed for loop or a `do..while` loop like this:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  var i = arr.length;
  do {
    if (Boolean(arr[i]) === false) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
    i--;
  } while (i > 0);
  return arr;
}
console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Comment: No worries, you already got my upvote (good spot on the skip).

Answer (score 1):

Because `Array.splice` is modifying the length of the array so `i` increments but the next item after a removal is actually at the same `i` numeric value index, so it ends up skipping the one that moves into the current index.

You could attempt to reconcile that by *not* incrementing i when you remove an item, or you can just move in reverse since the previous index will always remain as `i--`:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (Boolean(arr[i]) === false){
      arr.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  var resultArr = [];
  var k = 0;
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (!(arr[i] === false)){
     resultArr[k] = arr[i];
     k++;
    }
  }
  return resultArr;
}


var b = bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could not use splice and instead use array.filter, this seems far more efficient to me.

```js
const ar = [ false, 'foo', null, 'bar', 0, "", true, undefined, 1, NaN ];
const filtered = ar.filter(i => !!i);

const elem = document.createElement('span');
document.body.appendChild(elem);
elem.innerHTML = 'Filtered to: ' + JSON.stringify(filtered);
```

However to my surprise, perhaps it's obvious in hindsight, using `!!` to convert to boolean and then test is slower than directly comparing against a value like `false`, see this benchmark: https://jsbench.me/qvlbyyp8tk/1

Filtering using `i => !!i` is 33% slower than directly comparing `i !== false`.

I'm not sure how to insert benchmark tests in Stack Overflow, will update if I find out.